# How to show dropdown in PolkadotJS after selecting an item for extrinsic?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

First of all I apologise in advance for asking this weird question. I am not sure if this is the right forum.

I have a scenario, where I have a data structure and storage like this:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, Default)]
pub struct Department {
pub name: Vec<u8>,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, Default)]
pub struct Teacher {
pub id: TeacherId,
pub name: Vec<u8>,
}

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn teachers)]
pub type Teachers<T> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    DepartmentId,
    Vec<Teacher>,
    OptionQuery,
>;

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn schools)]
pub type Schools<T> = StorageDoubleMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    SchoolId,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    DepartmentId,
    Department,
    OptionQuery,
>;
```

I have a very simple extrinsic, where user has to pass school id.

Would it be possible to show a dropdown, once user enters school id? I do not want user to enter department id as an input?

Likewise, if above is possible, after selecting department from dropdown, would it be possible to show list of teachers in a dropdown?

Thanks in advance :)